# MySQL Query to sum data from another table in select query

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a hard time calculating the `items.sell_price` by the bill id.

This is my query.

```
    select bill.name,sum(item.sell_price) as 'price' 
    from bills,bill_information,items 
    where bills.id_bill = bill_information.bills_id 
      and 
          bill_information.item_id = item.id_item
```

But the problem is the sum doesn't work the way I want. I want to sum the `sell_prices` in table `items` when `bills.id_bill` has two `item_id` in the bill_information.

If we have two `item_id` in `bill_information` I want it to sum just those two, not all the `sell_price` in the `items` table

:( hope you get it

Comment: Why _"WITHOUT join's"_? The syntax you're using includes JOINS, but using the comma syntax.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I removed it from the title, I found them posts here that uses left join but that don't work for me, that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the table is doesn't matter in this case you have to do only one thing. please `group by` the `bill id` like below,

```sql
select bill.name,sum(item.sell_price) as 'price' 
from bills,bill_information,items 
where bills.id_bill = bill_information.bills_id 
and 
bill_information.item_id = item.id_item
GROUP BY bills.id_bill
```

the new part is,

```sql
GROUP BY bills.id_bill
```